# load element in directive angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to know how to insert a value into an input, when I insert a character, but by means of a directive, if I digito example: "enter" insert the word enter

```
<div ng-app="tomatela" ng-controller="somos" ng-model="numero">
```

```
   angular
.module("tomatela",[])
.controller('somos', function($scope){

})

.directive ('myEnter', function(){
  var linkFunction =function(scope, element, attrs){
     element.bind("keydown", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function (){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.myEnter);
                    scope.vamos="0,";
                  console.log(event.which);
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
  }
  return{
   restrict: 'A',
   scope: {
        cero: '@'
    },
    link: linkFunction
  }

})
```

here the codepen: http://codepen.io/fernandooj/pen/LRyLYb?

Comment: "*when I digito a character*" - you *what*?

Comment: @dfsq if I enter digit === 13, inserted into the input, the word ok